# MYSQL query too big

Tags: mysql

Despite 8gb of RAM, when I run this MYSQL query I get an error because memory runs. The reason is I have a huge amount of data:

```
`DELETE FROM bigtable_main where date = '2009-12-31';
```

Is there a way to split the above query up so that I can do rows 1 to 999,999 in one query, rows 1,000,000 to 1,999,999 in another query, etc.?

Answer (score 3):

You could use the `limit` keyword:

```
DELETE FROM bigtable_main where date = '2009-12-31' LIMIT 1000000;
```

You simply run this query over and over again until there are no rows left to delete.

DELETEing rows is more complex than you might guess, because MySQL's transaction semantics go to a lot of trouble to make it possible to roll back the deletion. If you do the deletion in smaller chunks (e.g. `LIMIT 1000000` or even `LIMIT 1000`) you demand less rollback work from the MySQL server.

Comment: Limit is fine but what about after 1000000 rows, assuming that the query crashes at 1000000 rows?

Comment: @ArjunSingh simply re-execute the query

Comment: you can offset the rows too `LIMIT 1000000, 1999999` but this would be only if you wanted to delete any rows after 1 mil.

Comment: Got it.  I guess I need to know whether the MYSQL query is crashing because it is deleting too many rows (in which re-executing the query multiple times would be the solution) or because it is evaluating too many rows (in which case using the offset function would be the solution).  Any thoughts?